# Angular alternativa a utilizar ng-init

Tags: angularjs

Esta es solo una duda así que no necesita bloque de código. Cual seria una alternativa a utilizar ng-init al momento de que se cargue una pagina un o un elemento cualquiera dentro de mi body. Al momento de que se cargue mi página necesito que se cargue algunos text-box con información de una bd. Deben cargarse los elementos pero sin utilizar ng-init, usando alguna alternativa. Soy nuevo en Angular y me gustaría su aporte y me serviría de mucho. De antemano gracias amigos y buenas tardes

Comment: "al momento de que se cargue una pagina un elemento dentro de mi body" no podía ser más ambiguo. A que te refieres exactamente. Edita la pregunta y agrega esa información.

Comment: Realmente no hay mejor alternativa que `ngInit`. Los constructores deben ser lo más ligeros posibles y la creación de instancias de servicios puede ser poco confiable. Los developers que lean tu código sabrán exactamente lo que intentas hacer. Otras alternativas no tienen ninguna ventaja notable, al final estas logrando lo mismo con código de peor calidad.